# External keyboard suddenly types two characters, is keyboard still recoverable?

Tags: keyboard, hardware-failure, troubleshooting

Suddenly tonight, I found out that when my external keyboard types two characters, it's still functioning properly this afternoon?

Pressing t inputs "tf"
Pressing y inputs "yJ"
Pressing a inputs "Tab + a"
Pressing S inputs "CapsLock + s"
Pressing Backspace inputs Backspace + \

What can I do to troubleshoot this? Is my keyboard still recoverable? Currently I don't have money to afford one for replacement

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it a wireless keyboard? Strange behaviour in wireless keyboards may be related to low battery or "noisy" environment (too many wireless devices nearby). Have you tried it on another computer?

Comment: Have you tried restarting? unplug and replug the keyboard? Changing the batteries?

Comment: No it's a USB. Yes I have tried restarting the OS and unplugging back the keyboard. Also it's a rainy damp night, I found my keyboard kinda cold from the weather, could this be connected to the problem?